# Non-genuine remote shutter release locks for too long: is it common issue?

Tags: remote, shutter-release

I'm doing self-portraits with my Canon EOS 1000D using a chip remote shutter release RS-60E3  and delaying shutter to 10s, so I can take the right position in front of the camera.

However, from time to time the remote shutter release locks for too long, causing my photographs to be overexposed.

My remote shutter release is not genuine one made by Canon but by Shoot Inc. So I was wondering if the described issue is common for those chip switches and original Canon switch has no such problems?

Comment: What exposure mode are you using? An 'Auto' mode or **P**, **Tv**, **Av**, or **M**?

Comment: Av. I had no such problems without the remote switch, so it's not a problem of setting the wrong exposure.

Comment: The remote doesn't affect the shutter speed in Av mode, it sends a signal to 'fire' to the camera and the camera does the rest.

Comment: Ok, clear, thanks. I will investigate further to better describe when it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how a problem with the remote could possibly affect the shutter speed (Tv) unless you have it set to 'Bulb', in which case one press of the remote opens the shutter (after the 10 second delay) and another press of the remote closes it. **When you have a specific shutter speed or aperture value set, the remote only sends a single signal that tells the camera to fire the shutter after the appropriate 2 second or 10 second delay. Once the signal from the remote is received by the camera, everything else is done by the camera.** It counts down from ten seconds and then takes the picture. If you are shooting in an automatic mode or one of the semi-automatic modes, the scene could be changing while the timer is counting down and metering is being done when the lighting is different than when the shot is actually taken.

Comment: I think I know what has happened. Light metering is done not at the moment of taking a photo by the camera, but at the moment of when I push the button in the remote, i.e. just before the camera starts counting down. This is pretty surprising... Anyway, either I need to set exposure completely manually or remember not to stand in front of the camera in black t-shirt when pushing the button.